# Running a REST server within Unity3d

Tags: rest, unity-game-engine, nancy

I'm trying to build a REST server within a Unity project and thought initially that Nancy seemed like the obvious choice. Many headaches later however and I'm still having trouble getting Nancy to run within the Unity Mono runtime - I can compile and run from Xamarin but Unity gives me rather unhelpful output whne I attempt to use the asset:

```
Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespace (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.LoadReferences () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I can't be the only person who has tried something like this, and am looking to use this across several projects, so having something re-usable is of high priority - has anyone successfully implemented anything like this, and if so can you give me any pointers?

I'd really like to get Nancy working, but another way of easily embedding a REST server would be just as valuable.

Comment: Just a longshot - but isn't this a problem of the .NET version? Unity3d last I used it was still on some 2.x version of Mono, and declared itself to be using a 'subset' of the .NET 2.0 runtime. In practice I found I can use various features of later .NET versions, but no all. Nancy on the other hand if I'm not mistaken aims to work from .NET 3.5 forward (but not on older versions).

Comment: Also found this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/636739/reflectiontypeloadexception.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread on Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/636739/reflectiontypeloadexception.html), it happened because the .NET subset that Unity uses did not include System.Web, so copying System.Web.dll v2.0.50727 to the project solved this problem.

However, if memory serves I recall an option in Unity to force it to use a full .NET 2.0 runtime rather than the subset, which might also solve the problem. It was a while since I used Unity, so the option might have been removed.

**Edit:** [See here](http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html) it's called "compatibility level".

**Edit 2:** It's in [Player Settings](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-PlayerSettings40.html)

Answer (score 0):

I never managed to get a http server running within the unity client, (the accepted answer looks right, but it was too late for me to test it, let me know if it doesn't work) it seems that at least in unity 4 the necessary parts of the mono runtime had been excluded. Things may be different in unity 5, I'm not working with unity at the moment so I'm afraid I'm not up to date.

With that in mind, the solution I opted for was a listening http client, with an external server - this worked reasonably well, however things become slightly more complex than necessary.

The other solution that I heard about later, is to use the Thrift protocol, there's an example at https://github.com/amilstead/unity3d-thrift-twisted which should be enough to get started, and there's support for Thrift in a wide variety of languages, the idioms are a little different to those of http, but generally this is likely to be the better fit for most circumstances where you would want an embedded http server.